# Player is not looking at correct direction

Tags: unity, rotation, quaternion, bot

My Enemy/Bot is facing the wrong direction as shown in the attached screenshot 1.
Basically what I want is that Enemy/Bot gun should directly face the player, not enemy/Bot himself.

> Note: White line in the image is representing Aim direction which is
> correct.

Here is my Code:

```
Vector3 targetPosition = kbcrd.playerToEngage.thirdPersonPlayerModel.shootTarget.position;
targetPosition .y = 0;

Vector3 botPosition = pb.thirdPersonPlayerModel.gunDirection.position;
botPosition.y = 0;

Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - botPosition);

//pb is Bot which is holding transform and other scripts.
pb.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(pb.transform.rotation, targetRotation, kbcrd.lookingInputSmooth);
```

What I Get from the above code is this: (Screenshot # 1)
[image]

---

What I want is this: (Screenshot # 2)
[image]

Guns And player Orientation:
[image]

Full function if needed:

```
public override void WriteToPlayerInput(Kit_PlayerBehaviour pb)
{
    CampaignModeControlRuntimeData kbcrd = pb.botControlsRuntimeData as CampaignModeControlRuntimeData;
    CampaignModeEnemyAI botCampaignModeAI = pb.gameObject.GetComponent<CampaignModeEnemyAI>();

    if (botCampaignModeAI.enemyInRange)
    {
        if (kbcrd.enemyPlayersAwareOff.Contains(botCampaignModeAI.detectedEnemies) == false)
        {
            kbcrd.enemyPlayersAwareOff.Add(botCampaignModeAI.detectedEnemies);
        }

        kbcrd.playerToEngage = botCampaignModeAI.detectedEnemies;
        //CheckForEnemies(pb, kbcrd);
    }
    else
    {
        kbcrd.playerToEngage = null;
    }

    UpdateAimPosition(pb, kbcrd);
    FiringDecision(pb, kbcrd, botCampaignModeAI.enemyInSight);
 }
```

Any help is appreciated. I know its simple problem but I struggling now. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@derhugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) for answering this on Stack overflow [Link to Answar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62508687/player-is-not-looking-at-correct-direction)

So the problem was basically the offset distance between the gun and the bot. So the Code mentioned in the question was just rotating Bot toward the player while not including the offset between the gun and bot. Here is the final code:

```
var targetPosition = kbcrd.playerToEngage.thirdPersonPlayerModel.shootTarget.position;
targetPosition.y = 0f;

var botPosition = pb.thirdPersonPlayerModel.gunDirection.position;
botPosition.y = 0f;

var gunForward = gunDirection.forward;
gunForward.y = 0f;

var botForward = pb.transform.forward;
botForward.y = 0f;

// Get the offset between the bot's and the gun's forward vectors
var gunBotOffset = Vector3.SignedAngle(gunForward, botForward, Vector3.up);
// Get a rotation to rotate back from the gun to the player direction
var gunToBotRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(gunBotOffset, Vector3.up);

// Add the back rotation to the target rotation
var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - botPosition) * gunToBotRotation;

pb.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(pb.transform.rotation, targetRotation, kbcrd.lookingInputSmooth);
```

**Note:** Mentioned code is the copy of the "@derhugo" code from stack overflow.

Comment: Please ask each question on just one site in the StackExchange network. Cross-posts will generally be closed.

Comment: @DMGregory, Sorry I didn't know that. Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link.
In your case, it would be, I think:

```
Vector3 targetPosition = kbcrd.playerToEngage.thirdPersonPlayerModel.shootTarget.position;
targetPosition .y = 0;

Vector3 botPosition = pb.thirdPersonPlayerModel.gunDirection.position;
botPosition.y = 0;

Vector3 targetDirection = targetPosition - botPosition;

float singleStep = speed * Time.deltaTime;
Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetPosition, singleStep, 0.0f);

pb.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);
```

I hope it works, I didn't try it :)

EDIT 1: This assume that you put this code in the update function

Comment: Thanks for your time. But unfortunately, it didn't work now bot doest now rotate but shaking on his position. I think what is happening is that bot moves toward the player a little bit and then reset direction because of that "transform.forward".

Comment: Can you send full script?

Comment: Sure I can but it's like more than 1000 lines of code. and a lot of other script references. Do you think it can help?

Comment: Just send the Update Function. Your code is from here right?

Comment: Yes, it is in the update function of another script. and what I shared above is the part that actually rotates the bot.

Comment: Ok then edit your post with the update function, I'll tell you if I need more info :)

Comment: Will, I added the full function at the end of the post.

Comment: Ok I thought about it a while. I think your code is rotating the enemy. But you should do the same code for the gun as well. It might be that

Comment: Well, I Got the issue was the offset between the gun and bot position, Bot was basically facing the correct direction but due to offset direction of the bot was off so after adding that offset it solved the issue and now it works up expectation. I will post an answer to it. And realy apretiate you time and effort. So Thanks A lot. :)